# Make JSOM a High Performance deliver

Tags: jsom, performance

- I have JSOM code with some functions , Where I am also using Jquery
  Data table with some controls in it.
- My SharePoint list is having 2000 items,When I bind the data to the
  Jquery Data table the page it taking 40-50  seconds to load the
  items.Can any one help me in knowing how can I increase the
  performance of the of JSOM

Comment: Please share your code...And Is your query/response from server taking this much time or the processing after getting the response ??